# How to run specific command while running all the script parallel

Tags: python, node.js, linux, shell, automation

I got script that are building images pushing them to docker hub and checking all the errors.
But my main purpose is to run specific command like "**node server.js**" and than start running the script commands.

and i want it to be in the same script file all together.

For now what i am doing is opening **2 terminals**, from the **First terminal** running the command '**node server.js**' to start the app.
And from the **Second terminal** running the script.

and what i want to is configure the 'node server.js' command inside the script to run at the background and let the script continue and the same time.

For now this is my script and when the script start running the command **os.system(start_node)** the script stop running to the other commands.
so my questions is how to run this command and let the script contiune without opening 2 terminal and run in 1 terminal node server.js and in the second the script without the command **os.system(start_node)**.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#Before running this script need to start the app 'node server.js'
import os
import sys
os.chdir ("/opt/new-test-app")

start_node = 'node server.js'
npm_test = 'npm test'
npm_output = '  8 passing'
image = 'docker build -t test/new-test-app-new:latest .'
test = 'curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://localhost:8081'
docker_login = 'cat /cred/cred.txt | docker login --username test --password-stdin'
docker_push = 'docker push alexkocloud/new-test-app-new:latest'

os.system(start_node)


os.system(npm_test)

if npm_output == 0:
    print ("npm test not succesfully passed")
    sys.exit()
else:
    print('npm test successfuly passed with "8 passing"')

if os.system(test) == 0:
    print('HTTP Status Code 200 OK')
else:
    print('ERROR CODE')
    sys.exit()

os.system(image)

os.system(docker_login)
os.system(docker_push)

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Is your script a `bash` script or a Python script? To start `node` server in the background, just add a space and `&` after the command.

Comment: python 3.7 , and i need to write it inside the script and not a single command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what i did is just added this line

**nohup node server.js > output.log &**

Inside my variable:
**start_node = 'nohup node server.js > output.log &'**

and it's working as i wanted.

If anyone has a better solution i would love to see.
Thanks.